# Markov chain simulation

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I'm wondering whether there is an algorithm to simulate a discrete Markov chain with a specific number of occurrences of state knowing the transition matrix way.

For example, how to simulate in `R` a Markov chain of length $n$ with $p$ occurrences ($p < n$)

```
TransitionMatrix<- matrix(c(0.7, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6),byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)
colnames(TransitionMatrix) <- c('0','1') row.names(TransitionMatrix) <- c('0','1')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an "occurrence". (I apologize for my ignorance in case this is standard terminology in Markov chain theory I just wasn't aware of.) I would guess you are saying you want to select a starting state, let the state evolve from one step to the next stochastically using the transition matrix to determine the probabilities of where you'll go next given where you are, do that $n$ times, and finally count the number of times $p$ you visited a particular state of interest. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @DanKneezel
Assuming that _n=20_,
rnd_occ1<-c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
and
rnd_occ2<-c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
 are two possible candidate having a such transition matrix.
Moreover the state "1" has 9 and 6 occurences in the 1st and 2nd sequences respectively.
What I'm looking for it is an algorithm or a library to simulate **efficiently** such a markov chain sequence with for instance 12 occurences of the state "1".

Comment: Got something from the answers?

Answer (score 4):

First a reformulation of the question, then a pseudo-algorithm to solve it.

**Reformulation:** Let $n\geqslant1$ and assume that $X=(X_t)_{1\leqslant t\leqslant n}$ is a Markov chain of length $n$ on the state space $\{0,1\}$ with transition probability matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1-a & a\\ b& 1-b\end{pmatrix}$ for some $a$ and $b$ in $(0,1)$.

Fix $k\leqslant n$ and consider the set $\Gamma_k^n$ of paths $\gamma=(x_t)_{1\leqslant t\leqslant n}$ of length $n$ visiting $k$ times the state $1$. For every $x$ and $y$ in $\{0,1\}$ and every path $\gamma$ in $\Gamma_k^n$, let $N_\gamma(xy)$ denote the number of times $t\leqslant n$ such that $(x_t,x_{t+1})=(x,y)$. Finally, let $M(\gamma)=N_\gamma(01)$.

Then, forgetting a possible discrepancy of $\pm1$ here and there, one sees that $N_\gamma(10)=M(\gamma)$, $N_\gamma(00)=n-k-M(\gamma)$ and $N_\gamma(11)=k-M(\gamma)$, hence, for every $\gamma$ in $\Gamma_k^n$,
$$
P(X=\gamma)=
(1-a)^{N_\gamma(00)}a^{N_\gamma(01)}b^{N_\gamma(10)}(1-b)^{N_\gamma(11)},
$$
is also, since $n$ and $k$ are fixed,
$$
P(X=\gamma)= (1-a)^{n-k-M(\gamma)}a^{M(\gamma)}b^{M(\gamma)}(1-b)^{k-M(\gamma)}\propto c^{M(\gamma)},
$$
where
$$
c=\frac{ab}{(1-a)(1-b)}.
$$
Thus, there exists some $A_k^n$ independent of $\gamma$ such that, for every $\gamma$ in $\Gamma_k^n$,
$$
P(X=\gamma\mid X\ \text{visits}\ 1\ \text{exactly}\ k\ \text{times})=A_k^n\cdot c^{M(\gamma)},
$$
and the question is to simulate a random path in $\Gamma_k^n$ following this distribution.

**Pseudo-algorithm:** This assumes one is able to generate uniformly subsets $T$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of size $k$.

- Choose a path $\gamma$ uniformly in $\Gamma_k^n$, that is, choose uniformly a subset $T\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of size $k$ and define $\gamma=(x_t)$ by $x_t=1$ if $t$ is in $T$ and $x_t=0$ otherwise.
- Compute $M(\gamma)$.
- Accept $\gamma$ with probability proportional to $c^{M(\gamma)}$.
- Repeat until a path $\gamma$ is accepted. Return $\gamma$.

To generate $T$, the following procedure might prove useful:

- Let $T=\varnothing$.
- Choose $x$ uniformly in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. If $x$ is not already in $T$, add $x$ to $T$.
- Repeat until $T$ has size $k$. Return $T$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm not sure I properly understand the pseudo-algorithm.
Please, could you develop into an algorithm?

Comment: What for? Please be specific.

Comment: if we assume _a=6/7_ and _b=1/2_, a possible path `γ=(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)`.
Nonetheless,the algorithm that you propose will not converge in this case. Indeed, the computation of c gives **c=6**, and hence c^M(γ) will be greater than 1.

Comment: Please read on my lips: `proportional to`.

Comment: What I'm saying is in the case c is greater than 1, then c^M(γ) will also be greater than 1 and therefore, it wouldn't be possible to find an integer **const** such that `P(X=γ∣X visits 1 exactly k times)= const*c^M(γ)`

Comment: Of course such a constant exists, always, since the paths gamma are in finite number (but the idea that this constant should be an integer is bizarre, in general this is simply a finite positive real number).

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have transition probabilities $p_1 \leq p_2 \dots \leq p_k$, $\sum p_k = 1$. Define the distribution function in pseudo code:

```
function cdf(state) { a = math.random() % randomly generated number in U(0,1)
if 0 <= a < p_1, return 1
if p_1 <= a < p_1 + p_2, return 2
...
if p_1 + ... + p_{k-1} <= a < 1, return k
```

In the above, I have assumed that the transition probabilities are all the same, i.e. independent of the state. Otherwise, the $p_i$ will have to depend on `state`.

The above code is just saying that if I have numbers $p_1$, ..., $p_n$ such that $\sum p_i = 1$, then I can partition the unit interval $[0,1]$ with these numbers. The area of the rectangle [$p_1 + ... + p_{k-1}, p_1 + ... + p_k$] with unit height is $p_k$, and that's the probability we want for the $k^{th}$ transition. This is the standard way of generating probability distributions, since if $X$ has cdf $F$, then $F(X) \sim U(0,1)$.

Now pick an initial state (say $s = 1$) and a state you want to measure, say $r = 4$.

```
count = 0
for i = 1 : n
   s = cdf(s) // transition with the appropriate probabilities
   if s == 4, count++
   end
end
```

I should mention this algorithm is the worst.

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. Should I delete my answer?